# Create duplicate rows based on conditions in SAS or R

Tags: r, sas, duplicates, copy

I want to copy rows in data set depending how many rows subject has in original dataset.

```
id x1 x2 x3 count
1  a  b  c  1
1  b  c  f  2
2  g  h  a  1
2  a  d  c  2
2  f  g  a  3
3  a  g  a  1
```

I have created this count variable to detect number of rows each subject has. 
(Don't mind about values of x1--x3, they are just here for illustration.) I have also much more subjects in actual dataset than these three.

Dataset, what I want should look like this.

```
id x1 x2 x3 count
1  a  b  c  1
1  b  c  f  2
1  a  b  c  1
1  b  c  f  2
2  g  h  a  1
2  a  d  c  2
2  f  g  a  3
2  g  h  a  1
2  a  d  c  2
2  f  g  a  3
3  a  g  a  1
```

I have tried following code

```
data want (drop=i);
set have;
by id;
output;
do i = 1 to count;
output;
end;
run;
```

But obviously it makes too many copies..

Any help with R or SAS is highly appreciated!

Comment: The logic is not clear

Comment: Shouldn't `id = 2` appear 3 times? (i.e. 9 total). If so, try this: `df[rep(rownames(df), with(df, ave(id, id, FUN = length))),]`

Comment: Mmm, so if In original dataset I have two rows for one subject then I want to create a new data where exisits those two rows plus two extra rows which are copys from original data. Same if number of rows for subject is three, then I want to create three extra rows in dataset, so the number of rows for that subject is six..

Comment: That count variable was made only for detecting the row number for all subjects, I think that might be eventually useless..

Comment: So something like `df[rep(rownames(df), with(df, ave(id, id, FUN = function(i)ifelse(length(i)>1, 2, 1)))),]`?

Comment: The meaning of the input variable COUNT is not clear. If COUNT=2 do you want to output that record 2 times or three times?  Your current code is doing the later. Your desired output is doing neither, it just seems to be outputting everything twice no matter what the value of COUNT.  Also does the order of the rows in the output matter?

Comment: Shouldn't ID3 be in there twice, if the rule is double?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[rep(seq_len(.N), pmin(2, .N))], id]
#    id x1 x2 x3 count
# 1:  1  a  b  c     1
# 2:  1  b  c  f     2
# 3:  1  a  b  c     1
# 4:  1  b  c  f     2
# 5:  2  g  h  a     1
# 6:  2  a  d  c     2
# 7:  2  f  g  a     3
# 8:  2  g  h  a     1
# 9:  2  a  d  c     2
#10:  2  f  g  a     3
#11:  3  a  g  a     1
```

Comment: @pinegulf Yes, it is an R solution using `data.table` package.  I didn't notice that there are multiple tags in the questin.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to DOUBLE the number of observations then just use two output statements. Or read the input dataset twice.

```
data want;
  set have have;
run;
```

If the order matters then you can double them by using two DOW loops.

```
data want;
  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    output;
  end;
  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Your input dataset does not appear to have the count of the number of rows per ID value.  If you had that variable (call it `NREPS`) then your DO loop to output replicates would be simple. If the goal is to have the number of extra copies depend on NREPS (so that you end with NREPS*(NREPS+1) observations per ID) then this code will work:

```
data want;
  set have;
  do _n_=1 to nreps+1 ;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

You could count in the same data step if you had to, assuming the data is sorted by ID.

```
data want;
  do nreps=1 by 1 until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
  end;
  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    do _n_=1 to nreps+1 ;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to 'double' your data set which seems unclear to me, here's one approach.

```
 *add data in twice;
 data want;
   set have have;
 run;

 *double the records;
 proc sort data=want; 
   by id;
 run;
```